# Error "Telerik is undefined"

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik

I am getting JScript error as "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Telerik' is undefined" while running my project.
I have just tried configuring the project from the menu bar 'Telerik->Rad controls for asp.net ajax->configure project' and it gives me this error.

Please find below my webconfig file. I could find some threads in Telerik forum about trouble shooting for the same but they didn't solve my issue.
I am using .net 4.0 version.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="xxx" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=False; User ID=abc; Password=xxxx;" />     
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Telerik.Skin" value="Default" />
        <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
        <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />            
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /></assemblies></compilation>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />    
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="RadCompression" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
            <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
            <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use this code in Web config,

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2009.3.1314.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" verb="*" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

and

```
<handlers> <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2009.3.1314.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" /></handlers>
```

I was able to run the Telerik with these two settings in Web Config

Comment: Thanks Prem.I already have these two in my http handler and handler,but only the 'type' changes.I dont have PublicKeyToken and version in type.I am using visual studion 2010 and .net 4.0.How can I know about the version and publictoken key as in yours (type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2009.3.1314.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4")

Comment: Any answer..please help me on this..It is very urgent

Comment: Got the version and token as below in the 'type' as below. type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2012.2.607.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" But still i am having the error as  'Telerik' is undefined

Comment: I hav added standard scriptmanager in my mark up and I am no longer getting this error message for the timebeing.Do Anyone know what should be done exactly to remove this error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Telerik 2013-3-1015` than replace

```
<add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
```

With

```
<add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.3.1015.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" verb="*" validate="false"/>
```

In `web.config`

to check your version of `Telerik`. Go to `Solution Explorer` -> `References` click on `Telerik.Web.UI` now in `Properties` windows check version attribute

Enjoy... !!!!

Comment: This was the solution for me, my App Pool is 2.0 and using ASP.NET 3.5 libs. I tried many solutions on the web and adding the version of my Telerik.Web.UI dll was the trick, thank you so much Ramesh!

Answer (score 1):

Please add these lines to the web config

```
<location path="Users/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

See if you have this line in your web.config and comment it out:

```
  <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information and scenarios for the error at https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/knowledge-base/common-error-telerik-is-undefined.