# Telerik control radscheduler not working properly on IE 11

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, telerik, scheduler

I have a radscheduler. It shows up correctly and work as intended on IE 10. There is another workmachine of mine and it has upgraded to IE 11. The radscheduler does not show properly at all. Instead of 1 radscheduler it shows 2 and no css, no styling and just super weird looking. How should I proceed? Please ask me questions if you need more info. Thanks
EDIT:   I got a javascript error saying "Telerik is undefined" in IE 11. But it is there. I mean it works in Firefox.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? IE11 support was added with the most recent service pack.

Comment: @M4N.I am. It says 2013. I have been getting varied errors now. One of my guess is Windows update on the server is not up to date. The last time it was updated was march 20 of this year. Have to run the update in the weekend. Also, one thing I noticed is once I deleted the temp internet files and played between changing IE 10 to IE 11 it worked. Its bizare.

Comment: Check if you are using version 2013.3.1114. See here: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/whats-new/release-history/q3-2013-sp1-version-2013-3-1114.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The Telerik is undefined error is discussed in the following help article https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/general-troubleshooting#error-message-telerik-is-undefined-when-running-a-website-on-iis-7-integrated-mode and in StackOverflow too [Error "Telerik is undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929178/error-telerik-is-undefined).